# Liquibase drop all functions - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, maven, liquibase

I need some tips on how to how define a custom "worker" or "profile" for Liquibase. I would like to use the drop-all task from Maven(3.3.5), but it does not remove functions from the database. (PostgreSQL)

Comment: Do you mean the version of liquibase-maven-plugin ?

Comment: what's this "cuz task" thing?

Comment: Project is based on spring-boot (1.2.4.RELEASE), liquibase-hibernate4 (3.5), liquibase core (3.4.2) and liquibase-maven-plugin is same as core liquibase. (*cuz /because)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write an extension to Liquibase that would be able to query Postgres for the list of functions, as well as code to generate the correct SQL for Postgres to drop functions. This will not be a trivial exercise.

The basics of writing a Liquibase extension are described [on the Liquibase website](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Liquibase+Extensions+Portal), but it would require a fair amount of learning to understand the Liquibase internals.